# Can't assign value to string (Eclipse CDT, MinGW, C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, string, mingw

I'm trying to declare a string variable and put the text "hello" into it, but it won't run. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello!" << endl;

    int b = 12;
    cout << b << endl;      

    string a;
    a = "hey";

    return 0;
}
```

Building the program works just fine (from what I can tell). When I run this program, Eclipse's console window shows me nothing, and at the top it says: " (exit value: -1 073 741 511) IfStatement.exe [C/C++ Application] C:\Users\My_Username\OneDrive\Programming\Eclipse\IfStatement\Debug\IfStatement.exe (15.05.2016, 01.53)".

When I remove this part:

```
a = "hey";
```

everything works as expected. It's the actual value assignment of the string that is ruining the program somehow. What is going on?

Thank you for your time, feel free to ask if you need more information.

Comment: Works fine for me http://ideone.com/i35t40 .

Comment: That's weird, could I have runied something on my end during configuration or installation? Other programs seem to work just fine, I just can't assign string values into string variables.

Comment: I tried this exact program in Visual Studio, and it runs perfectly. I don't really know what the problem is in Eclipse, but I've probably made a mistake when installing or setting up either MinGW or Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the program is executing the return statement and exiting before you can see the output. Before the return statement, throw in a getchar() call, or use system("pause"). This will freeze the console window and allow you to see the output, which should be "Hello!" followed by "12" on the next line.

Comment: This did not help. system("pause") gives me a red squiggly line, the same with getchar(). I'm really new to C++ syntax. I tried googling the use of each command, but no matter what I tried, I got red squiggly lines for both. I however tried cin.get(); but that didn't do anything, still the same weird exit code. Also, I don't think the problem is that the program executes too fast, because when I remove the a = "hey"; line, I get all the other output. Further suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem in Eclipse, because the code works fine when I run it in Visual Studio 2015. I would create the default Hello World program in eclipse and run that. If you get the same error, then it's just an IDE problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've abandoned Eclipse and gone over to Visual Studio because that works. Thanks for the help! :)